# Changing the behavior of the marshmallow schema when used as nested

Tags: python, marshmallow

For example, I have a base schema and two schemas used this base. And I have an id field as dump_only=True in my base schema like this:

```
class BaseSchema(Schema):
    id = ObjectId(required=True, dump_only=True)


class AuthorSchema(BaseSchema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    surname = fields.String(required=True)


class BookSchema(BaseSchema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    author = fields.Nested(required=True, nested=AuthorSchema)

author_schema = AuthorSchema()
book_schema = BookSchema()
```

An author's id should only be required at dumping. But an author is used as nested field in book (as book's author), id should be required both of loading and dumping.

It may seem like a simple problem and can be solved like this:

```
class BaseSchema(Schema):
    id = ObjectId(required=True)


class AuthorSchema(BaseSchema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    surname = fields.String(required=True)


class BookSchema(BaseSchema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    author = fields.Nested(required=True, nested=AuthorSchema)


author_schema = AuthorSchema(dump_only=('id',))
book_schema = BookSchema(dump_only=('id',))
```

But I have a lot of schemas like this schemas with nested fields. I think this solution may mislead someone who is not familiar with marshmallow and not very good in terms of readability. Because base schema says something like this: "Id field is required for every operations.". I'm looking for a different solution. Is there a way to solve this in the field.Nested definition?